# How to craft a variable expliciting the difference of another variable in R?

Tags: r, dataset, dplyr

I'm trying to create a variable that express the difference of an existing variable over time. 
I have tried to craft this by mutation command using the dplyr package but without result, the new variable is sorted by a country variable. 
In other words, what I'm asking for help to is the craft the column 'Mutated' in the example below.

```r
df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year,Data,Country,Mutated,
1,3,US,NA,
2,4,US,1,
3,2,US,-2,
4,7,US,5,
5,4,US,-3,
1,3,UK,NA,
2,5,UK,2,
3,4,UK,-1,
4,3,UK,-1,
5,2,UK,-1,
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
df2
```

Any help is greatly appreacited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the difference of Data values per country over time, you can have the use of `lag` function as this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(M2 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 0, Data-lag(Data)))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Country [2]
    Year  Data Country Mutated X        M2
   <int> <int> <fct>     <int> <lgl> <dbl>
 1     1     3 US           NA NA        0
 2     2     4 US            1 NA        1
 3     3     2 US           -2 NA       -2
 4     4     7 US            5 NA        5
 5     5     4 US           -3 NA       -3
 6     1     3 UK           NA NA        0
 7     2     5 UK            2 NA        2
 8     3     4 UK           -1 NA       -1
 9     4     3 UK           -1 NA       -1
10     5     2 UK           -1 NA       -1
```

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, M2 := fifelse(seq_len(.N) == 1, 0, Data - shift(Data)), Country]
```